# ERROR: log4j.appender.DEBUG

Tags: java, tomcat, log4j

Hola agradezo su ayuda con el siguiente caso:

Tratando de habilitar en rootCategory el nivel de DEBUG, asi:

```
log4j.rootCategory=INFO,CONSOLE,DEBUG
```

Subiendo el servidor tomcat 7 sale el siguiente error:

```
log4j:ERROR Could not find value for key log4j.appender.DEBUG
```

La configuracion del log4j.properties es la siguiente:

```
log4j.rootCategory=INFO,CONSOLE


log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %X{requestId} %-5p %c %x - %m%n

log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
#log4j.appender.file.file=${log4j}
log4j.appender.file.file=/tmp/mercury.log
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %X{requestId} %-5p %c %x - %m%n

log4j.category.com.mercurytfs=ERROR 
log4j.category.com.mercurytfs.mercury.modules.integration=ERROR
log4j.category.org.springframework=ERROR
log4j.category.org.springframework.integration = ERROR
log4j.category.org.springframework.http.converter.json=ERROR
log4j.category.org.springframework.web.client=ERROR
log4j.category.org.springframework.security=ERROR
log4j.category.com.fasterxml.jackson = ERROR
log4j.category.org.hibernate=ERROR
log4j.category.org.hibernate.engine.transaction=ERROR
#log4j.category.org.springframework=ERROR
#log4j.category.org.springframework.data=ERROR
log4j.category.org.dozer=ERROR
log4j.category.org.apache.commons=ERROR
log4j.category.org.apache.commons.beanutils.converters=ERROR
log4j.category.org.aspectj=ERROR
log4j.category.org.jgroups=FATAL
log4j.category.org.quartz=FATAL
log4j.category.com.iterative = ERROR
log4j.category.org.hibernate.SQL=ERROR,a3
log4j.category.org.hibernate.cache=INFO
log4j.category.net.sf.ehcache = INFO
log4j.category.org.springframework.security.ldap=ERROR
log4j.category.org.apache.activemq=INFO


log4j.appender.a3=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.a3.MaxFileSize=100MB
log4j.appender.a3.MaxBackupIndex=10
#log4j.appender.file.file=${log4j}
log4j.appender.a3.file=c:/tmp/logs/xxxxx.log
log4j.appender.a3.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.a3.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n
```

Comment: No uses INFO y DEBUG al mismo tiempo, solo usa uno de ellos. Tu resultado debería ser: `log4j.rootCategory=DEBUG,CONSOLE`...

Comment: Hola @LuiggiMendoza muchas gracias, ese era el error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El nivel base o raíz para todos tus loggers no puede tener dos valores, solo puede tener uno. Debes definir que sea `INFO` o `DEBUG` o algún otro valor. Tu problema se resuelve así:

```
# log4j.rootCategory=INFO,CONSOLE
log4j.rootCategory=DEBUG,CONSOLE
```